# Infer type from function in a promise block in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm very new to typescript and I wanted to try and reduce my usage of try...catch blocks by creating a one liner method. the issue that I have is that I don't know how to infer or create a correct return type that my VS code intenseness recognizes the result value.

I was initially trying to get it to work using generic types but I don't think that's the correct approach.

```
// My try catch block
async function solve<T>(fn: T) {
  const res = await fn;
  if(res)
    return [res, false];
  return [null, true];
}
```

```
(async ()=>{
  const [a, b] = await solve(new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve({
        n: 1
      })
    }, 2000)
  }));

  // I want to get suggestion that "n" is a property of returned "a".
  console.log(a)
  // this gives typescript error
  console.log(a.n)

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Firstly you need to annotate your functions and Promises with the correct type information. So your `solve` method should look like this :

```
async function solve<T>(fn: Promise<T> | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<[T, false] | [null, true]> {
  const res = await fn;
  if (res)
    return [res, false];
  return [null, true];
}
```

And you should call your function with the generic `Promise<T>` :

```
const [a, err] = await solve(new Promise<{ n: number }>(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        n: 1
      })
    }, 2000)
  }));
```

Even if you do so you will need a not-null assertion to bypass the possible null exception like below :

```
if (!err) {
    // I want to get suggestion that "n" is a property of returned "a".
    console.log(a)
    // this gives possible null exception but  I think its a limitation.
    console.log(a!.n)
  }
```

This is some kind of limitation of Typescript it fails to narrow down the type correctly depending on the array elements. If you were using an object instead of an array it would work without exception  :

```
async function solve2<T>(fn: Promise<T>): Promise<{ result: T, isError: false } | { result: null, isError: true }> {
  const res = await fn;
  if (res)
    return { result: res, isError: false };

  return { result: null, isError: true };
}

 if (!res.isError) {
    console.log(res.result)
    console.log(res.result.n) // n is inferred correctly and no possible null exception here 
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIxOgNgNwFMAeAFQD4AKOCALhgAUAndAW1RBIpgB9GX2nADKoA1l3IBKeszYcSAbVIAaeMFycAurxgKICXLlXImCQpvIwA3gCgYMKJhDIYTQiBgBeGMADuwVBcaAG47GFQ4GEo3EEkw+zdkBCYsBRjVOHUtUITCJJTdfUNjU3NQgF8bG1BIWEQUDCwcAkIAJjIqGhkBeQ7pfjlOYitXdwNkehVwkABRJhYmekyNQhhynRGY8foio2m5hfoTMzXLW3tHCGdRj28-AKCIHPDI6Pc4+1z8rE2x3AmbqoOAd0Is1Cs1qEwolkj8btsYLsgbN5qCjqVITZKjZKDVoFFJF4zmFLtcFMBVIR5to7v5Atg8ERKBBCL4BoISCM6IiEKwAEZU05vZpEInWeLYPKkVCsQjoBDISiUQmeYmfT4xRmESjndWfbkARgl9nKH0+5VUrQADDazabJFD7BEogBCKlMQm6+wAem9MAAkjB-BAXMh0DAAOZ5bAICNR5yNGDIAAWwBcACIIOnpj4YAAHFh5qnIMAwdCRGEpQgAExg6eA6YAdBLSXhCI3cOgI7izT6-SmOJHUEQPHn0CAQKg+bhVrsYIQAB5QQh5tCYGB8hX2QMDiCicLIDzAGC4GWBNONZvq1szjtd3EuxsQO0kpwuGJeHx0lwitrM1nsr0XI7LyApMEKmotGKXqSsg0qyvKirKtBxo3FqOqofYhqoaaEoWjA1q2mE9rPM6lAujEjbAqiHriteThtne3aUVs-y9g4DG3p2zHuI2rHIE+L5YpIyrBEAA)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your response. firstly regarding why I used array instead of object initially was that if I had to write multiple solve instances within the same file or function I have to map out and destruct them one by one.

something like {result : res1, isError: err1} where as in array I can just get the response and if it's an object destruct it within the array [{ n }, isError] this is me just being lazy.

Comment: on the other point, where you explicitly defined  `new Promise<{ n: number }>` in most case I have the object but sometimes the issue I had was with `prisma` where my intenseness broke when I tried to access the inner object properties, that I had to import as individual types which was kind of annoying. I was hoping it could pass its types to the result.

Comment: @Bardia in Typescript if you don't use `Promise<T>` it is defaulted to `Promise<unknown>` if your promise comes from somewhere else it might contain the correct type parameter but if it's not you should somehow correct it someplace in the call chain.

Comment: you're absolutely right and I failed to take note of that. and the function you've provided worked great by the way.